# Why am I getting a 404 Error when Deploying Google Cloud NodeJS Application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, deployment, web-deployment

I'm building a NodeJS/React app in the Google Cloud Console. The app runs correctly with npm run preview when in the vite-project directory. However, when I try to deploy by cd'ing into Top_Level_Directory and running gcloud app deploy, I get an error 404 in the deployment URL. I am guessing the issue is in my app.yaml or folder structure. Can anyone find the error?

Folder structure:

- ```
  Top_Level_Directory:
  ```
- ```
  —package.json
  —package-lock.json
  —app.yaml
  —vite-project
    —node_modules
    —style.css
    —router.jsx
    —package.json
    —package-lock.json
    —main.jsx
    —index.html
    —home_page.jsx
    —favicon.svg
    —App.jsx
    —node_modules
    —dist
       —index.html
       -assets
         -index.bab0b7c5.css
         -index.6689790b.js
         -favicon.17e50649.svg
  ```

App.yaml:

```
# [START cloud_tasks_app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs14

# [START cloud_tasks_app_env_vars]
env: standard
# [END cloud_tasks_app_env_vars]

# Handlers for serving the index page.
handlers:
  - url: /vite-project
    static_dir: /vite-project
  - url: /
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index.html
# [END cloud_tasks_app_yaml]
```

Comment: Update: I have now tried adding app.yaml to my vite-project folder and running deployment from that directory. App.yaml looks like this: ```runtime: nodejs14

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index.html
``` And error is "Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js'"

Answer (score 0):

`npm run preview` relies on `npm run build` being run **first** to populate the `dist` folder with generated static assets. Your `static_dir` in `App.yaml` should point to this `dist` directory so that the files therein may be served.

I recommend overhauling your project structure to  separate static, generated, and dynamic assets.

> Example Structure

```
—vite-project
  —dist
     —index.html
     -assets
  —node_modules
  -public
    -favicon.ico
    -index.html
    -manifest.json
    -robots.txt
  -src
    —style.css
    —router.jsx
    —main.jsx
    —home_page.jsx
    —favicon.svg
    —App.jsx
  —package.json
  —package-lock.json
  —app.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll be sure to adjust the folder structure. Can you clarify what should be in app.yaml? I currently have the following in the top level path: ```# [START cloud_tasks_app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs14

# [START cloud_tasks_app_env_vars]
env: standard
# [END cloud_tasks_app_env_vars]

# Handlers for serving the index page.
handlers:
  - url: /vite-project
    static_dir: /vite-project/dist
  - url: /
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index.html
# [END cloud_tasks_app_yaml]``` and it is not working when running gcloud app deploy from that directory. Getting a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

Edited app.yaml in the vite-project folder as follows:

```
# [START cloud_tasks_app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs14

# [START cloud_tasks_app_env_vars]
env: standard
# [END cloud_tasks_app_env_vars]

handlers:
# Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
  # catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

Then ran cloud app deploy (as well as any npm commands) from within the vite-project folder.